# SQL: Update a column with multiple values with single query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an update query like following:

```
update table TABLE1 set COL1 = 'X' where COL2 = 'Y' ---1
```

Support the values 'X' and 'Y' are fetched from database now TABLE2. E.g.

```
select COL1, COL2 from TABLE2. ----2
```

I want to update table TABLE1 with values from TABLE2.

Just to make it more clear, assume that TABLE2 has following values:

[image]

Can you please help me in doing this in a single query!

I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: @Sandeep Jindal, What is your RDBMS?

Comment: http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/01/31/update-data-in-one-table-with-data-from-another-table/

Comment: Why don't you say what is your RDBMS??

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for suggest. Work on the same! Improvement shall be reflected soon (24 hours) :)

Comment: @Sandeep You might be interested in this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost ready to begin beta, just needs a few more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Oracle, this is the most basic way to do it:

```
update TABLE1
  set COL1 = (select TABLE2.COL1 from TABLE2 where TABLE2.COL2 = TABLE1.COL2)
  where COL2 IN (select TABLE2.COL2 from TABLE2);
```

This can be inefficient in some cases since it could execute a subquery for every row in TABLE1.

Depending on the declaration of primary key or unique constraints on both tables, you may be able to use the updateable inline-view method, which is probably more efficient:

```
update
  (select TABLE1.COL1 as T1C1, TABLE1.COL2 as T1C2, TABLE2.COL1 as T2C1
     from TABLE1 join TABLE2 on TABLE2.COL2 = TABLE1.COL2
  )
  set T1C1 = T2C1;
```

Answer (score 2):

@Dave Costa's answer is correct, if you limit yourself to `update` statements.  However, I've found that using a `merge` statement in these situations allows me to do this in a more straightforward manner:

```
merge into TABLE1 
      using TABLE2 
      on (TABLE2.COL2 = TABLE1.COL2)
when matched then
     update set TABLE1.COL1 = TABLE2.COL1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update TABLE1 
set TABLE1.COL1 = TABLE2.COL1
from TABLE1
join TABLE2 on TABLE1.COL2 = TABLE2.COL2
```

(this would work on Sql Server)

Comment: Don't you think that `table` keyword is redundant here `update table TABLE1 `?

Answer (score -3):

for oracle:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
 SET (X,Y) = (SELECT X,Y from Table2 WHERE ...YourConditions...)
WHERE ... Another Conditions ...
```

for mysql, sql-server

```
UPDATE t1
 SET t1.X = t2, t2.Y = t2.Y
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.Something = t2.Something
```

Comment: MySQL's `UPDATE` statement doesn't have a `FROM` clause.

Comment: I need to update TABLE1, as following: 

update table TABLE1 set COL1 = 'X' where COL2 = 'Y' . Both the values(lists) is gathered from TABLE2. I am not sure if your query: 

UPDATE Table1 t1 SET (X,Y) = (SELECT X,Y from Table2 WHERE ...YourConditions...)

Suppose I don’t have 'Another Conditions'. Would not this query update all the value of TABLE2 (and not just values of COL1 for which COL2 matches in TABLE2)?